# What does new* mean in Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

For example, in the circled part in this image: [image: Illustration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints.html) showing the author name. `new*` means it has not yet been committed to the git repository. You can turn off such hints by right-clicking on one of them and choosing "Disable".